# Google App Engine Entity.getProperty return Chinese as?

Tags: google-app-engine, character-encoding

Insert one record onto GAE data store, and the Chinese is OK, from GAE admin console "datastore viewer", as [linked](https://appengine.google.com/datastore/explorer?&app_id=s~andrewwang1-app&version_id=3.361798798511158961).

But if I browser it from servlet, the Chinese is display as "????". The servlet code as

```
resp.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
...
Entity e = entities.iterator().next();      
String d = (String) e.getProperty("date");
String c = (String) e.getProperty("course");                    
resp.getWriter().println(d + " " + c);
```

Really trouble me lots, any clue helps. THANKS...

Answer (score 1):

This is a known deficiency of development server admin pages.

There is nothing wrong with your code or data, just how data is displayed in dev server admin pages. I get the same thing with the Slovenian characters, but it all works well in production.

Answer (score 0):

It's on the Google App Engine, not the dev server. But finally I know why I forget to call the super.doGet() in the Servlet doGet() method.

After that the Chinese is display correctly...

BTW, thanks...